# Eclipse shows errors in Play 2.4 setup

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to setup an Scala SDK Eclipse-based IDE to work with Play 2.4 on Windows 8. I followed instructions given on [the official guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Eclipse), but after opening default view index.scala.html, I get a bunch of errors like:

1. > ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
   >
   > both method *display* in
   >   class BaseScalaTemplate of type (o: Any)(implicit m: Manifest[error])
   >   and  method *display* in class BaseScalaTemplate of type (x: error)
   >   match argument types (play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable) and
   >   expected result type Any
   >
   > Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
   >
   > index.scala.html  /play-scala-test-app/app/views  line 3
   >
   > Java Problem
2. > type Html is not a member of package play.api.templates
   >
   > index.scala.html  /play-scala-test-app/app/views  line
   >
   > Java Problem

I tried to remove default imports and add new import `play.twirl.api._` in the `Play2` project properties, but that changed nothing. Is there a way to fix the configuration?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Any luck fixing it?

Comment: I have the same issue too. Any news?

Comment: Same problem.
Play 2.4.2, Scala-IDE 4.1.0 (for scala 2.11.7), Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the first issue, but the second one is caused by outdated SbtEclipse plugin. Because of that `target/scala-2.11` subfolders are not being added as source paths to the project.
To fix this:

- bump SbtEclipse plugin version to 4.0.0: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`
- run `sbt eclipse` from project's root directory
- refresh the project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/WFNoQ6GNw1k

1 Fork https://github.com/cweinreben/scala-ide-play2

2 Checkout the project locally

3 Execute ./build.sh in root of the project folder (wait and drink a cup of coffee while it downloads the internet)

4 When finished switch to Eclipse and open the "Install New Software..." Dialog (Menu "Help>Install New Software...")

5 The build script creates a update site - so select "Add" in the dialog and then "Local..." and switch to the folder "scala-ide-play2/org.scala-ide.play2.update-site/target/site"

6 Install the feature in this folder